# Placing items below category in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

So I wrote a small shopping list application using Django. Users may enter their desired items which are stored in a database alongside a category they reside in to make the list presented to the user more clean and giving them (the users) a good overview of what they are going to buy.
The goal is to show the user a list which is categorized, something like this:

VEGETABLES

- Paprika
- Tomatoes

VARIOUS

- Toothpaste
- Toilet Paper

And so on. I have like five categories saved in my database and users may choose one corresponding category once they add an item to the list below which the item will be displayed in the list.

These are my database models:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    count = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

this is my views.py

```
def items(request):
    item_list = Item.objects.order_by('id')
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    form = ItemForm()
    context = {'item_list' : item_list, 'form' : form, 'categories' : categories}
    return render(request, 'buyit/index.html', context)
```

and this is my index.html (very basic, stripped off all the css and html stuff):

```
        {% for category in categories %}
        <h4>{{ category.name }}</h4>
        {% for item in category.item_set.all() %}
        {{ item.text }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

I got this functions from the Jinja2 template from a code snippet and it might be, that I didn't understand it correctly.
However, the debugger tells me:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'category.item_set.all()'
```

Any hints on what I am doing wrong?
Simply displaying the categories worked fine but after adding

```
    {% for item in category.item_set.all() %}
    {{ item.text }}
    {% endfor %}
```

things crashed.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `()` in django templates. Just remove them to call the function / method.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#variables

> Behind the scenes
> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute or method lookup
> - Numeric index lookup
>
> If the resulting value is callable, it is called with no arguments. The result of the call becomes the template value.

Comment: So you mean just removing the brackets would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

views.py:

```
def items(request):
    commoditys = {category: Item.objects.filter(category=category) for category in Category.objects.all()}
    form = ItemForm()
    context = {'commoditys' : commoditys, 'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'buyit/index.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
{% for category, commoditys in commoditys.items %}
  <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>
  {% for commodity in commoditys %}
    {{ commodity.text }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Change the Category variable to a dictionary, where the Key of each item is the Category object, and its corresponding value is the item Queryset it belongs to